# Where is Corev4.css located in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to make a copy of the default css file from the master page, but I'm unable to locate the physical file. Can someone help me find this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my understanding its not stored in the styles library, so in that case it would be stored in 14hive:

dont overwrite sharepoint corev4.css, instead ovwerite it in another style, if you want to overwite with the same id or class that is fine! just use !important after each item eg:

```
.S4-td
{
   width:100% !important;
}
```

Important overwites any other css! having `After="corev4.css"` will do it aswell ;) but if you want to explicitly say you only want that style then i would put the method above!

to use above in custom css use this in masterpage:

```
<!-- link to our custom css  -->
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="/_layouts/customcss/css/style.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

or

```
<!-- link to our custom css  -->
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="/Style%20Library/style.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

just for reference if you want to do above but want to know what classes and id's are in v4 than its located here:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\corev4.css

[Cannot locate corev4.css file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41351/cannot-locate-corev4-css-file)

in your case you want to copy the covev4.css, thats fine! in your masterpage you need to add your custom css file as above, goto corev4.css and copy everything and paste into the custom css file that you just made! now in the custom file you can do what you want! if changes dont persist than use !important as iv stated ;)

Comment: that cool! allways happy to help :)